# @Inject not working for CDI bean

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss

I am trying a very simple example on JBOSS.

I have following class defined

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject; 

@Singleton
@Startup
public class PRCConnectionRunner {

@Inject
private PRCConfiguration prcConfiguration;

@PostConstruct
void printthing() {
    System.out.println("HI");

    System.out.println(prcConfiguration== null);
}   

}


public class PRCConfiguration {
 public String greet(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + ".";
    }
}
```

I have my beans.xml defined in the WEB-INF directory and i am packaging this as a war from maven.

However when i deploy and start this on JBOSS server, I do get the HI printed but the dependency is not injected because i get true for the null test.
What am i doing wrong?
I believe since @PostConstruct method is invoked i am missing some small detail.

Comment: What version JBoss? Do you have a web.xml file? If so what version is specified in that?

Comment: <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it. The issue was beans.xml was stored in an incorrect location.

The beans.xml should always be at for a web application.

src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\beans.xml

If you use eclipse/jboss, a quick way is to just check if the deployed resources menu is populating the beans.xml. When i placed it at the right location, jboss automatically updated the deployed resources menu item.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From CDI 1.1 not every class are managed by CDI context. You have to specified it by **annotation** or put `bean-discovery-mode="ALL"` in your `beans.xml`, then use [`@Vetoed`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1-PRD/javax/enterprise/inject/Vetoed.html) on class which should not be managed by CDI. Default value is `bean-discovery-mode="ANNOTATED"`.
My recommendation is annotate your class with proper annotation(depends on life cycle of the bean).

Also check if your bean.xml file is located in ..\webapp\WEB-INF\beans.xml

[Default CDI Enablement in Java EE 7](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/default_cdi_enablement_in_java)